# Sending a few values using Bundle

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass values from `MainActivity`

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!allAnswersChecked())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", R.string.text_not_checked);

            else if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);

            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED",getString(R.string.text_not_checked));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

to `AnswerActivity` (which partly I've already done)

```
TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String name = bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED",getString(R.string.text_not_checked));

textViewDisplayResult.setText(name);
```

But how to send the other two `"KEY_ANSWER"` values from `MainActivity`? By simply adding something to this line?

```
String name = bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED",getString(R.string.text_not_checked));
```

***And another question***

The "KEY_ALL_CHECKED" has a boolean value in its method

```
private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in `AnswerActivity` I pass it using `getString`. Is that ok? I'm getting a bit confused (the code works).

Thank you in advance.

POST UPDATE

```
private static int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;
static boolean[] answer = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] checked = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];

PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnswerActivity.class);

    buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (allAnswersChecked())
            {
                if (checkAnswers())
                    intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);
                else
                    intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);
            }
            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.text_not_checked);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1))
                checkSelected();
            else if (buttonCheckAnswer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

public static void checkSelected() {
    for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
        if (radioChecked) {
            buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}


private boolean checkAnswers() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : answer) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

AnswerActivity code

```
 package make.appaplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);


        String answer = "";
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ANSWER"))
                answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER");
        }
        Log.d("SUCCESS", "answer: " + answer);

        textViewDisplayResult.setText(answer);
    }
}
```

Here is a bit changed `buttonCheckAnswer` method. It now gives me text `"Good answer"` and `"Wrong answer"` in the right way. Only `"You haven't checked all answers"` doesn't show at all when needed.

```
 buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (allAnswersChecked()) {
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "You haven't checked all answers");
            }
            if (checkAnswers())

                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "Good Answer");

            else intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "Wrong Answer");



            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure your if-else conditions are OK? Do you want to pass both KEY_ANSWER and KEY_ALL_CHECKED always to your AnswerActivity?

Comment: Hi Ferdous. Not always. It depends on what and how many `rbs` are pressed by user. Feel free if you have any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your `MainActivity`, modify your `conditions` as below:**

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnswerActivity.class);

        boolean isAllAnswered = allAnswersChecked();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isAllAnswered value is: " + isAllAnswered, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

        if (isAllAnswered)
        {
            boolean isGoodAnswer = checkAnswers();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isGoodAnswer value is: " + isGoodAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

            if (isGoodAnswer)
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "Good Answer");
            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "Wrong Answer");
        }
        else
            intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", "You haven't checked all answers");

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**In your `AnswerActivity`, get `values` as below:**

```
    String answer = "";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ANSWER"))
            answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER"); 
    }

    Log.d("SUCCESS", "answer: " + answer);

    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
    textViewDisplayResult.setText(answer);
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Hello Ferdous. Could you please adivse me on my other issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945129/getting-constant-false-value-from-method

Comment: If my answer seems useful, then please give an upvote

Comment: You helped me a lot! Here is my upvote for you. Thanks for yours. I hope you'll be willing to help me next time. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure anytime... I have also added answer for your another question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to pass all the values, even is you have if..else if..else. "How to pass other two `KEY_ANSWER`? ..." Why are you using same key for both? Use different keys for both and add both strings to the bundle. Try following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED","YOUR_STRING_VALUE");
extras.putString("KEY_ANSWER_ONE","YOUR_STRING_VALUE");
extras.putString("KEY_ANSWER_TWO","YOUR_STRING_VALUE");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

and when you want to get extras, get three different Strings by their keys as following:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String str1 = extras.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED");
String str2 = extras.getString("KEY_ANSWER_ONE");
String str3 = extras.getString("KEY_ANSWER_TWO");
```

And you will get all strings in str1, str2 and str3.

Comment: Thanks. In `AnswerActivity` I get now `str1,2,3` is never used and in `textViewDisplayResult.setText(extras);` `extras` is underlined red.

Comment: you can't set `extras` object as a String. Set the retrieved str1, str2 or str3 as per your need.. @Ramona

Comment: So what to use insted of `extras`? And how to set these str1, str2 or st3 properly?

Comment: extras are used for getting those strings. now str1 is your name, str2 is your first key answer and str2 is your second key answer. @Ramona

Comment: so do something like `textViewDisplayResult.setText(str1);`

Comment: and what about `str2` and `str3`? Will these be displayed too?

Comment: No man! it's your wish whether to display them or not in your application. I've only given the answer of "How to pass more than one values via bundle" :) @Ramona

Comment: Your code works but every time gives only one value - the last one `str3`. How to solve it?

Comment: because of your if else. Remove them once and check .

Comment: But.. using `textViewDisplayResult.setText(str1)` will only call `str1` to display. The `str2` and `str3` aren't used at the moment so they obviously won't be shown....And when I remove `if else` it gives an error.

Comment: @Ramona So you want to display all strings in one text view?

Comment: Yes! :) depending on user's choice - if he chooses `all good answers`, `all wrong answers` and  if he somehow `won't choose all of the answers`

Comment: then append the strings and display them @Ramona

Comment: okay! see this: `textViewDisplayResult.setText(str1 + str2 + str3);` @Ramona

Comment: Now all answers are displayed at the same time :)