# Getting constant false value from method

Tags: java, android

I have 3 questions

```
 private static int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;
static boolean[] answer = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] checked = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
```

and when NOT all questions are answered I have a method

```
private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
```

to show text `"You haven't checked all answers"`

The problem is that somehow it returns only `false` even when all `rbs` are pressed. Another words text `"You haven't checked all answers"` is still displayed even when all `rbs` are already checked.

How to change the above method?

**OR MAYBE**

it happens coz the values in this line

```
static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
```

don't change AT ALL. Maybe some extra code must be added to method `setOnCheckedChangeListener` which so far checks only if answers are correct or not.

Here is my code for `rb` [0]

```
 rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checked[0] = true;
                answer[0] = true;
            } else {
                checked[0] = true;
                answer[0] = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I see the part of the code that print the message? How do you check the rbs¡?

Comment: When you check a `RadioButton` are setting the boolean to `true`? If yes, how do you check them?

Comment: @AlexMamo. Hello. This is acutally the mistake here because when I check `rbs` the value stays the same [0]=false, [1]=false and [2]=false.

Comment: @DamianLattenero Hello there. . I check it with `setOnCheckChangedListener`. But all this works well. The only thing is like in my above post to Alex. I guess this method must be wrong somehow

Comment: @AlexMamo. Hello, I've updated my post with `setOnCheckChangedListener` where actually I don't have an update of arrays in `isAnswered`. How to add it to this method?

Comment: How many RadioGroups in your layout? How do you store answer?

Comment: @Ferdous. Hi, I've added ,just a few minutes ago ,these two lines to the `setOnChecked....` method - to `if` statement `isAnswered[0]=true` and to `else` statement `isAnswered[0]=true`.It works :) The method for storing is `allAnswerChecked` which returns `false` if not `rbs` are checked and `true` if all `rbs` are checked. THANKS A LOT FOR YOU EFFORTS. I'M SO HAPPY I CAN COUNT ON YOU.

Comment: @FerdousAhamed. Is it possible for you to upvote my post? I wanna reach this 'magic' 20 reputation so I can use chat here. It's pretty hard for the beginner to reach this 20 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you updating **isAnswered** array. In the code snippet you have provided, it updates only answer and checked arrays.

Probably that is why you are always getting false for all 3 array elements of **isAnswered** array.

Where are you updating **isAnswered** array. In the code snippet you have provided, it updates only answer and checked arrays.

Probably that is why you are always getting false for all 3 array elements of **isAnswered** array.

Hi Roman,

I believe you have multiple radio groups each with 3 radio buttons. If that is the case, just slight modification in you above code snippet should work for you.

```
rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checked[0] = true;
            answer[0] = true;
        } else {
            checked[0] = true;
            answer[0] = false;
        }
        // update isAnswered[0] to true. as this gets invoked when you choose any radio button.
        isAnswered[0] = true;
    }
});
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Ravi. Yes you right. That is why. What code add to `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for `isAnswered` to work properly?

Comment: Hey Ramona, i have updated answer. let me know if this helps and if so, pls accept my answer.

Comment: Yes it did. The same answer's been  given already and I came up finally with a very similar one. I will accept your answer. Please upvote mine if you would like to. Thanks Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS]; // initially all false

.............
....................

rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checked[0] = true;
            answer[0] = true;
        } else {
            checked[0] = true;
            answer[0] = false;
        }

        // Update value as user selected radio button
        isAnswered[0] = true;
    }
});
```

Do same for your other `RadioGroups`(`rg2, rg3, ......`). Hope this will help~

Comment: Great, this is also a good solution, even better than mine :)

Comment: You are accepting an answer that was edited 40 mins ago. But i have given the same solution before that. Its really unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry Ferdous. I apologize. Didn't notice it. Of course I accept your answer. No problem at all. Let's say Ravi was eager to help too. Is all ok now?

Comment: Just let me know if everything is ok now, Ferdous.

Comment: @FerdousAhamed when there are multiple interraction elements involved, it saves a few lines by letting the class implement RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeLsitener and using a switch to determine the view pressed.

Comment: I know that.... If there is more than one radiogroup, its better to implement OnCheckedChangeLsitener  and use swich-case for different RadioGroups. But i think this kind of optimization is not necessary for OP's question as it was not the actual requirement. But we can suggest him to follow this way for better coding. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a quick class to validate your logic and found no problems in your implementation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;
    static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBooleanValues();
        allAnswersChecked();
    }

    private void setBooleanValues() {
        isAnswered[0]=true;
        isAnswered[1]=false;
        isAnswered[2]=true;
    }

    private void allAnswersChecked() {
        for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
            if (!radioAnswer) {
                //return false;
                Log.d("allAnswersChecked","false");
            }
            else {
                Log.d("allAnswersChecked","true");
            }
        }
        //return true;
    }

}
```

See the log output :

```
05-12 16:43:10.299 8448-8448/com.example.myapplicationtest D/allAnswersChecked: true
05-12 16:43:10.299 8448-8448/com.example.myapplicationtest D/allAnswersChecked: false
05-12 16:43:10.299 8448-8448/com.example.myapplicationtest D/allAnswersChecked: true
```

So I recomment to print values and check if it is being correct set into your isAnswered array before calling allAnswersChecked().

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you for you help. The thing with this `buttonCheckAnswer` is that no matter if  `rbs` are pressed or not I always get [0]=false, [1]=false and [2] false so there is some mistake out here :(

Comment: Sorry for my late reply on this. So, that's what I was trying to tell you. You should check the code that sets values into your isAnswered array as the code you have posted here is free from bugs.