# How to set onBackPressed in Second Activity

Tags: java, android

I set the `<button>` in `activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="ReturnHome"
    android:text="Go Back"
    android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

And now I'd like to add `onBackPressed` method in `AnswerActivity`

```
public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
```

To be able to go back to previous page which is `Fragment`.

Can somebody guide me step by step how to do it?

**Edit:**

I wrote something like this

```
     super.onBackPressed();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        finish();
```

But it says 'variable "returnIntent" is never used'. How to fix it?

Comment: Show us what did you try and please be more specific

Comment: Hello, I've updated my post.

Comment: where are you adding fragment? show that code

Comment: @NJ, please explain more, what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant the physical button on the device, this is done by overriding:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

And your code:

```
super.onBackPressed();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    finish();
```

Shows returnIntent is never shown because you never called startActivity (intent). And you have to make sure you add a target.

Comment: did you read the question properly? OP want to go to the previous fragment.

Comment: Clearly the question was clear. Though he want to go to previous fragment on onBackPressed but he still shows us xml code for Button

Comment: @Swarnveer, so what 'she' :) can show you to be more specific and clear?

Comment: Sorry for "he" I didn't knew. And earlier I meant, "the question wasn't clear". It was was a type

Comment: @Swarnveer, no problem at all :) Just please help me if you can.

Comment: @LunarWatcher. I appreciate your efforts. It is as you said a `physical button` and your second option is a good way to follow. But what to write inside this method `onBackPressed`?

Comment: You need to override onBackPressed using Ctrl + O

Comment: I didn't understand what is the Button for when you want things to be done in onBackPressed

Comment: @Swarnveer the xml with the button threw me off, first OP says (s)he wants to use onBackPressed while showing XML code for a .xml button. I showed both solutions as it is very hard to understand which OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Ramona You use this code: `FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack();`

Comment: @LunarWatcher. Many thanks Lunar. Tell me please how to 'add this target'? I get now `getActivity` in red.

Comment: That is from a fragment. If you call it from an activity remove getActivity

Comment: Many thanks Lunar. Could you please have a look at my other issue?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945129/getting-constant-false-value-from-method

Comment: @LunarWatcher. Hi Lunar. Just came accross your answer and thought maybe you would be able to help with this issue..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997655/zoom-in-out-the-whole-page-layout. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ramona looking at both those questions. But if this answer worked for you, please mark it as the solution(to let others know this problem is answered and solved)